# Xcode 9.1 Refactoring not available

Tags: swift, xcode, refactoring

The refactoring menu in Xcode 9.1 is completely greyed out. I wanted to extract a method from existing swift code and got the following screen:
[image]

Do I have to enabled something special to get access to the new refactoring features?

Comment: Make sure you select code for which a refactor is relevant. For example, if you select the beginning of an if statement but not the closing brace, you won't see any refactor options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try cleaning your Xcode. Also try clearing out derived data and restart Xcode.

```
Clean Build --> (Command-Option-Shift-K)
Delete DerivedData folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Comment: Refactoring works only after the build of the project. And if you refactor one variable, then something else can not be refactored until the project is rebuilt. [ Xcode 9.3.x-9.4.x ]     Think different, again :)

Comment: This did not work for me. In my case, refactoring options are not greyed out, but when i click extract to method, nothing is happening.

Comment: It worked after restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change to the Active Schema to the one that matched the Target Membership of the file I was editing.

In other words:

- In Project Navigator, select the file you're editing
- Show the Inspectors panel on the right
- Show the File Inspector
- Observe the Target Membership values and set the Active Schema (at the top, by the Build and Stop buttons) to match.
- Select text, right click, select Refactor
- Observe all the Refactor options are now enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor option hides if you select version editor.
Thanks @paul

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too and I could not find anything on it so...

My first post is born.

Mike T. hit on a small portion above (incomplete syntax).

Nothing is wrong. Xcode is amazing! It seems the Refactor/Extract feature is pretty smart. The option is not available if it does not make sense to extract a method.

It may not make sense to extract a method for many reasons. Xcode disables the feature when it encounters them in the selection. A few that I noticed are:

- variable declarations
- a solitary print statement
- continue statements in the selection but I don't include the for loop container. (i'm impressed)

my guess is that there are a bunch of conditions...

Comment: Refactor can be *removed* from the Editor menu rather than disabled, at least when the version editor is selected (a HIG violation IMHO). This answer is helpful because it reminded me to check for other "does not make sense" conditions. Keep it up, Sachi!

Answer (score 0):

Small thing for me was that the code I was trying to access was inside a closure so when I was selecting it and right clicking to Extract to a Method, it was greyed out. removing self on both instances, I could then select both lines to then extract to method

```
self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
self?.activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
```

Both lines were inside a closure for a UIAlertAction. So removing self allows you to extract to a method in this case. Then just call self on the extracted method inside the closure and it should work.

```
self?.hideSpinner() //extracted method name
```

As other posters have already said, its best to make sure you're able to refactor what you want by selecting the right code.